# setState not updating when set to boolean

Tags: reactjs

I have the following method in a react component:

```
handleCheckBoxClick() {
  var checkbox = document.getElementById("boldCheckbox").checked;
  this.setState({ischecked : checkbox});
  if(this.state.ischecked) {
    this.setState({weight:'bold'});
  } else {
    this.setState({weight:'normal'});
  }
}
```

but if I change the if statement to:

```
if(checkbox) {
  this.setState({weight:'bold'});
} else {
  this.setState({weight:'normal'});
}
```

it works fine but I can't figure out why the first way doesn't work.

Comment: Setstate is executed asychronously, so you can’t expect the state to be updated right away

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method [`setState()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) is asynchronous, and updates are often batched together. In your case, `ischecked` is updated together with the `weight`, so when you set the `weight` you still refer to the old value.

One solution is to use `setState()`'s callback that will be called after the state is updated.

**Note:** to get the checkbox `checked` state, use the event object `e` passed to the handler instead of querying the DOM.

```
handleCheckBoxClick(e){
   var checked = e.target.checked;
   this.setState({ischecked : checked}, function() {
     if(this.state.ischecked){
        this.setState({weight:'bold'});
     }else{
        this.setState({weight:'normal'});
     }     
   });
}
```

A better solution is to update both properties because you know if the checkbox is checked:

```
handleCheckBoxClick(e){
   var checked = e.target.checked;

   this.setState({
    ischecked : checked,
    weight: checked ? 'bold' : 'normal'
   });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thats cause `this.setState({ isChecked : checkbox });` has not finished before you ask it in the if statement.